# Data from the Great Lakes Science Center's Annual Bottom Trawl and Acoustics Surveys

Tags: data-request, federal, usgs

The USGS's Great Lakes Science Center surveys fish populations every year in the Great Lakes. The results are [compiled into reports](http://www.glsc.usgs.gov/reports), but is the underlying data available anywhere?